# Entire "placed image" visible when exported when using "draw inside" tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text-wrap

Using Illustrator, I am trying to export my project to .png.  I have created a wrapped text with a placed image in it, using the Draw Inside tool.  Everything looks great on the screen (the first attached image), but when I go to export, the placed image is in front of everything else (the second attached image).  I'm assuming it has something to do with the wrap text because I've done it before with normal text.  Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Kellie, welcome to GDSE. I'm assuming you mean text *warp* not wrap? Have you tried expanding the warp, does that make a difference? Also adding details of how you are exporting would help (format etc). You can [edit] your question to add any more relevant info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

- Convert your text to outlines (**Type > Create Outlines**)
- Select your outlined text and convert it to a Compound Path (**Object > Compound Path > Make**)
- Now place your image **behind** this Compound Path
- Select both the path and the image, and create a Clipping Mask (**Object > Clipping Mask > Make**).

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you! It worked!  I don't know why I didn't think of that.  You rock!